# Override the values while returning in db

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I am having an issue with modeling of Java types in database. The problem goes as follows:

I have an customer category type(table customer_category), which has columns

```
{id,  category , discount, days_allowed, fine, customer_category}
```

In this table, what I need is, the value of discount,days_allowed and fine are based on the category, and if category is not defined for the customer he should get the default values of these columns. The values differs for % of discount.
The forth column customer_category, refer to the row it will override. If it is blank it will be added in the result , if its not then it will override the values with the given id

```
{ 1, "", 6% ,10 , $10, ""}
{ 2, "", 10% ,20 , $15,""}
{ 3, "", 15% ,25 , $20 , ""}
{4, "gold",10% ,5,$9 ,2}
{5,"silver",6%,9,$9 ,1}
{5,"platinum",7%,9,$9 ,""}
```

In the given example, say suppose I want to read all the discount available for gold category. it should return me these records.

```
{ 1, "", 6% ,10 , $10,""}
{ 3, "", 15% ,25 , $20,""}
{4, "gold",10% ,5,$9 , 2}
```

As 4th row points to row 2 in last column hence it is overwritten.

And if I want to read all the discount for category Platinum (which does not point to any row ), I should get following.

```
{ 1, "", 6% ,10 , $10, ""}
{ 2, "", 10% ,20 , $15,""}
{ 3, "", 15% ,25 , $20 , ""}
{5,"platinum",7%,9,$9 ,""}
```

How I can achieve that?